# Get sum of minutes of specific project

Tags: laravel

I want to get total minutes. Example: joylinkhk 240 + 180 = 420. How can I get a total minute of a specific user?

[image]

**controller**

```
public function search(Request $request) {

    $date = explode(' - ', $request->date);
    $auth = Auth::user();

    $hourLog = Hourlog::with('project', 'user');

    if ($auth->user_type == 1) {

        $hourLog->where("user_id", $auth->id);
    }

    $data = [

        "date" => $date,
        // 'projects' => Project::whereIn('id', $request->project)->get(),
        'projects' => Project::with('users')->whereIn('id', $request->project)->get(),

        'users' => User::with(['hourlog' => function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereIn('project_id', $request->project);
        }])->whereIn('id', $request->user)->get(),
    ];

    return view('cms.projectreport.projectreport-list', $data);
}
```

**HTML view**

```
@foreach($users as  $user)   
    <tr> 
      <td>{{$user->name}}
      </td>
      @foreach($user->hourlog  as   $hourlogs)
      <td>{{$hourlogs->hour_work}}
      </td>
      @endforeach
    </tr> 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @danny-van-der-sluijs said, you can use `sum` on a collection

```html
@foreach($users as $user)   
    <tr> 
      <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
      @foreach($user->hourlog as $hourlogs)
          <td>{{$hourlogs->hour_work}}</td>
      @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach

<tr>
    <td>Grand Total</td>
    <td>{{ $users->sum(fn($user) => $user->hourlog->sum('hour_work')) }}</td>
</tr>
```

Note:

```php
$users->sum(fn($user) => $user->hourlog->sum('hour_work'))
```

Is an [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) that came with php 7.4, If you are using a version below 7.4 you have to do it like this

```php
$users->sum(function($user) {
    return $user->hourlog->sum('hour_work');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Laravel collections are very powerful and offer such functionality out of the box.
Below is a example of how you can take a collection of arrays and sum by its property `hour_work`. The collect function is a quick way to create a collection like the `$user->hourlog` already is.

```
    collect([
      ['hour_work' => 198],
      ['hour_work' => 93],
      ['hour_work' => 51],
      ['hour_work' => 112],
    ])->sum('hour_work');
    // Result: 454
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sum in `foreach` loop, but get the result outside of `foreach` loop. You need to define first the variable outside of foreach `$sum_total = 0;`, then you can sum inside foreach like this :

```
<?php $sum_total = 0; ?> // define here
@foreach($users as  $user)   
    <tr> 
      <td>{{$user->name}}
      </td>
      @foreach($user->hourlog  as   $hourlogs)
      <td>{{$hourlogs->hour_work}}
      </td>
        <?php
          $sum_total += (intval)$hourlogs->hour_work 
        ?>
      @endforeach
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $sum_total }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Seems like the `@php` tag not worked, I updated, would you try again?